# Access instance property from enclosed class

Tags: java

I'm a newbie on java, in this example is it possible to get the id of ClassA from ClassB?

```
public class ClassA {

    private Long id;

    private List<ClassB> listOfClassB;

[...]
}

public class ClassB {

    private Long num;

    public boolean isValidRow() {
        return this.num > ***ClassA.this.getId()***;
    }

[...]
}
```

Comment: yes, if you create an instance of the `A` class

Comment: Read about encapsulation.

Comment: If in class A you pass 'this' to B and add mutators (or change id to public) then yes, otherwise it is impossible from your current snippet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - access private instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794295/java-access-private-instance-variables)

Answer (score 0):

For getting the `id` field of `ClassA`, you need to have an instance of `ClassA` in `ClassB`, for example:

```
public class ClassA {

    private Long id;

    private List<ClassB> listOfClassB;

[...]
}

public class ClassB {

    private Long num;
    private ClassA a;

    public ClassB(Long num, ClassA a) {
        this.num = num;
        this.a = a;
    }

    public boolean isValidRow() {
        return this.num > a.getId();
    }

[...]
}
```

And initiate it this way:

```
new ClassB(1, new ClassA(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public class ClassB {

    private ClassA a;
    private Long num;

    public ClassB(ClassA a){
        this.a=a;
    }

    public boolean isValidRow() {
        return this.num > a.getId();
    }
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
...
ClassA a = new ClassA();
ClassB b = new ClassB(a);
...
```

Or if you create Bs inside A:

```
ClassB b = new ClassB(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for nested classes only:

```
class ClassA {
    private long id;

    class ClassB {
        ClassA.this.getId(); // Will work here
    }
}
```

To make it work in your case you need inject instance of ClassA to instance of ClassB:

```
class ClassA {
    long id;
}

class ClassB {
    private ClassA a;
    ClassB(ClassA a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    void someMethod() {
        long id = a.getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the id of `ClassA`, but you can get it from **instance** of `ClassA`

For example:

```
    ClassA a =new ClassA():
    ClassB b =new ClassB(a);
```

ClassA:

```
public class ClassA{
   private Integer id;
   public Integer getId(){return id;}
}
```

ClassB:

```
    public class B {
     //whatever
     private A a;
     public B(A a){
        this.a=a;
     }

    public void someMethod(){
      //whatever
      t.getId() // here you have the id.
     }
}
```

now everywhere in your `ClassB` you will have access to `a.getId()`.